# keep socket open in node + express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am making a webapplication with multiple pages using nodejs, express & socket.io. One of the features is push notifications. This means socket.io should be running on every page. Connecting to socket.io on every page load takes a lot of time, which slows down the app.

Is there a way to keep the connection to the socket open?

One way would be to use ajax to render different pages inside my root page, but I think this will over complicate the app.

Is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're handling the client side the right way ?

If you have a single page application, the browser should almost never reload completely the page. You should be using some client-side framework to handle SPA mechanisms (routing, templating, etc) like angularjs/backbone/ember/etc...

With a well formated SPA you load your app only once and it is kept alive without page reload as long as the browser tab is opened. So you weboscket would be created also only once. You shouldn't have any problem of this kind, your server side code is OK, it's just that you're doing it wrong client-side.

By the way, if you want to do handle only push data, you should take a look at the [Server Sent Events](http://cjihrig.com/blog/server-sent-events-in-node-js/), which is simplier/lighter that a full-duplex implementation like socket.io (which is a bit heavy)